# Interchange max and sup in a function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

Define $\Psi$ as the space of functions $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and a subspace $\Phi \in \Psi$ which include all the monotone non-decreasing continuous functions on $[a, b]$.

Define a mapping $A: \Psi \to \Psi$. What condition $A$ should have such that:
$$
\sup_{g \in \Phi} \int_{a}^{b} (A\circ g)(x) dx = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sup_{g \in \Phi} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (A \circ g)(x_i) \delta   
$$
where $x_i = a + (i-1)\delta$ and $\delta = (b-a)/N$. $A \circ g$ are integrable functions. We also know that the left-hand side of the equation is finite.

Comment: What does the star mean?

Comment: @MikaelHelin Sorry, it is just 'times'.

Comment: @Duncan A is not the characteristic function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question completely. To show that the limit and sup can be interchanged I believe it suffices to show that the sequence of "integrals"
 on the LHS converge uniformly to the RHS

Comment: @Duncan Do you mean for any given $g$, $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum = \int $ is uniformly?

Comment: @ftor if I understand your question, yes. lim and sup can be interchanged provided there is uniform convergence

Comment: @Duncan I see. I have two questions. 1. Why? 2. For a function, how do I prove the infinite sum converges to the integral uniformly? What conditions do I need here? Thanks!

Comment: @Duncan I think you are right. The problem is how to prove the infinite sum is uniformly convergence on the space $\Phi$.

Comment: @Duncan Is $\Phi$ a compact set?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A=A(y)$ is unbounded for some number $y$ then you can always choose $g$ which is always constant to make always unbounded. We have shown that $A$ must be bounded.

The case with piecewise constant $A$ is trivial.

For each interval from $I_n=[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ there is a point $x'_n$ and $a_n$ such that $a_n=\sup_{x\in I_n} A(\phi(x))=A(\phi(x'_n))$. If you sum all $a_n$ and then take limit then you get
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \sup_{x\in I_n} A(\phi(x)).
$$
For each interval $I_n$ choose a point $x''_n\in I_n$ and then you have $b_n=A(\phi(x''_n))$.
If you sum all $b_n$ and then take limit then you get
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N A(\phi(x''_n))\leq \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N A(\phi(x''_n)).
$$
To obtain
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup_{x''_1,\ldots,x''_N}\sum_{n=1}^N A(\phi(x''_n)).
$$
you let $x''_n\to x'_n$.

Comment: Hi Mikael, since the function is integrable, for any given $g$, the limit of the infinite sum equals to the integral. That is not a problem. The problem is whether we can change the limit and the sup. Thanks.

Comment: The solution covers interchanging $\sup$.